# How to have my program return to the main menu?

Tags: java

At the second while loop (after the person selects the coin toss simulator option) I am having issues when the user selects 0 the program doesn't back out to the main menu as I would like it to, instead it just stops, and doesn't cycle through back to the main menu for the user to select another option.

Any ideas how to fix this? I cannot use multiple methods as this is a requirement for a project I am doing. I've been stuck on this one part for a long time now, (a week) and would gratefully appreciate any pointers or directions.

Here is what my program looks like when the user selects zero after running the coin toss simulator.

===== CS302 TOOL BOX =====

T > COIN TOSS SIMULATOR

G > GRADE ESTIMATOR

C > COLOR CHALLENGE

Q > QUIT

Type code letter for your choice: t

COIN TOSS SIMULATOR

Enter 0 to quit. How many tosses?

4

2.0 heads and 2.0 tails means 50.0% were heads

Enter 0 to quit. How many tosses?

3

3.0 heads and 0.0 tails means 100.0% were heads

Enter 0 to quit. How many tosses?

0

(THEN IT JUST STOPS INSTEAD OF REDIRECTING BACK TO THE MAIN MENU)

```
  {        
           Scanner anotherScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            boolean usersSelection = false;

            outer:
                while (!usersSelection)
                { 
                    System.out.println("===== CS302 TOOL BOX =====\nT > COIN TOSS SIMULATOR\nG > GRADE ESTIMATOR\nC > COLOR CHALLENGE\nQ > QUIT");
                    String c;
                    System.out.print(""+ "Type code letter for your choice: ");

                    if (anotherScanner.hasNext("q|Q"))
                    {

                        c = anotherScanner.next();
                        //usersSelection = true;
                        System.out.println("\n Good-bye");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (anotherScanner.hasNext("t|T")){

                        c = anotherScanner.next();
                        usersSelection = true;
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("COIN TOSS SIMULATOR");
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit. How many tosses?");

                        Random rand = new Random();

                        Scanner insideScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                        int feeble = insideScanner.nextInt();

                        double heads = 0;
                        double tails = 0;
                        boolean hvt;



                        while ( feeble != 0 ) { //Pay attention to this while loop

                            if (feeble == 0){break outer;}

                            for (int i =0; i < feeble; i++) {
                                hvt = rand.nextBoolean();

                                if (hvt == true){ heads++;}

                                else {tails++;}

                                }


                        System.out.println(heads + " heads and " + tails + " tails means " + (heads/(heads+tails)*100 + "% were heads"));
                        System.out.println("Enter 0 to quit. How many tosses?"); //I ask the question again
                        heads = 0;
                        tails = 0;
                        feeble = insideScanner.nextInt();//I get new input

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: `if (feeble == 0){break outer;}` How could this possibly be true? Your `while` loop only executes on the condition that `feeble != 0` and I don't see you changing the value of `feeble` before that `if` statement. So, pretty sure that condition will always be `false`.

Comment: I've tried to place it outside of the while loop but it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

`usersSelection` is still true, so the outer loop (`while(!usersSelection)`) doesn't run again.

Also, `if (feeble == 0){break outer;}` is redundant, and even if it did actually work, `break outer;` would end the program (by exiting the outer loop).

Comment: Then would I say something like if (feeble ==0)(usersSelection = false)?

Comment: That code (`if (feeble == 0){break outer;}`) *never runs*. Delete it so you won't confuse yourself.

Comment: The reason is that if feeble is 0, the code inside while loop (`while(feeble != 0)`) wouldn't be running, so the if statement wouldn't even be reached.